# How make multiline fields in GROCERY CRUD?

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, grocery-crud

What do I need to change to make two lines (or more) fields presentation in GROCERY CRUD (CodeIgniter framewoks)?

In [examples on site](http://www.grocerycrud.com/examples/offices_example) I see table like I need. 
But I make view and see my table like [this example](http://www.grocerycrud.com/examples/employees_example)

I have some columns 50-100 characters long, and I need to show all content of them. But now I getting something like `My field cont...` instead of:

```
'My field 
content'
```

Comment: Can we see your code in the question? Links break, so we try not to rely on them.

Comment: Thanks should be never be provided in a question (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour): no chit-chat)

Comment: What code do you need? Code in examples almost totally equal to mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using GC version 1.3+, you can change `grocery_crud_character_limiter` config option to zero:

```
//The character limiter at the list page, zero(0) value if you don't want character limiter at your list page
$config['grocery_crud_character_limiter']   = 30;
```

in this file:

> application/config/grocery_crud.php

This is system-wide setting. If you want to affect only some lists, you will have to add some code:

```
$crud->callback_column('text_to_show', array($this, '_full_text'));

function _full_text($value, $row)
{
    return $value = wordwrap($row->text_to_show, 100, "<br>", true);
}
```

Credits goes to this page: http://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/339-list-showing-data-row-without-limitation-of-chars/